# MYSQL ERROR: Illegal Mix of Collations

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1267

i am receiving the following error message

> [Err] 1267 - Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT)
>   and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='

Subquery contains Union of two tables from two different databases. The query i am trying to execute is given below

> ```
> SELECT  c.CORRECTION_NO FROM    (
>     SELECT  "regm2017" as `SESSION`,SERIALNO,NAME,FATHER
>     FROM    regm2017.master r17
>     WHERE   r17.IS_DELETED=0
>     UNION
>     SELECT  "regm2016" as `SESSION`,SERIALNO,NAME,FATHER
>     FROM    regm2016.master r16
>     WHERE   r16.IS_DELETED=0
>     ) as r JOIN    corrections_registration as c ON      c.SERIALNO = r.SERIALNO
>     AND c.`SESSION`= r.`SESSION`;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It happened due to variation in collation.If you give any values explicitly in Query,collation be will taken from Connection.

You can use something like this.

> ```
>      SELECT c.CORRECTION_NO FROM (
>      SELECT "regm2017" COLLATE utf8_general_ci as > `SESSION`,SERIALNO,NAME,FATHER
>      FROM regm2017.master r17
>      WHERE   r17.IS_DELETED=0
>      UNION
>      SELECT  "regm2016" COLLATE utf8_general_ci  as `SESSION`,SERIALNO,NAME,FATHER
>      FROM    regm2016.master r16
>      WHERE   r16.IS_DELETED=0
>      ) as r JOIN    corrections_registration as c ON c.SERIALNO = 
>      r.SERIALNO 
>      AND c.`SESSION`= r.`SESSION`;`
> ```

OR

> ```
>   SELECT c.CORRECTION_NO FROM    (
>   SELECT  "regm2017" COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci as `SESSION`,SERIALNO,NAME,FATHER
>   FROM    regm2017.master r17
>   WHERE   r17.IS_DELETED=0
>   UNION
>   SELECT  "regm2016" COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci as `SESSION`,SERIALNO,NAME,FATHER
>   FROM    regm2016.master r16
>   WHERE   r16.IS_DELETED=0
>   ) as r JOIN    corrections_registration as c ON      c.SERIALNO = r.SERIALNO
>   AND c.`SESSION`= r.`SESSION`;
> ```

Comment: please some format this answer,I cant do it in my machine